# MySQL - optimize insert after truncate

Tags: mysql

I have real-time changing data (about 40 000 records) which I need to grab and insert into MySQL table each 5 minutes. I can't track certain changes to the data source, so I am making "TRUNCATE TABLE ...; " followed by bulk insert "INSERT INTO (..., ..., ...)." with all 40k rows.

However, there is a short delay between table being truncated and new data being inserted in table. Therefore, there is a short period of time when my table is empty and my website shows no data.

Is there any way to optimize this process? I read about INSERT DELAYED, but it's only working with MyISAM, and I am using InnoDB for my tables.

Comment: Have you considered just renaming the table instead of re-loading the data?

Answer (score 1):

a better option would be inserting data into a new table, then renaming (swapping) both tables in a single command. The rename operation is done atomically, which means that no other session can access any of the tables while the rename is running, see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/rename-table.html